# How to combine two integers into one string without malloc using C?

Tags: c

I want to combine two integers into one string in the following format: `x-y`. I wrote this function and it works perfectly, but the problem is I don't want to use malloc or any other memory allocation to do this.

```
static char* intToTimeDate(int day,int hour){
    size_t size = 32;
    char *str = malloc ( size);
    snprintf ( str, size - 1, "%d-%02d", day, hour);

    return str;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use `malloc`, then how are you going to allocate memory for a string?

Comment: mm i don't have to write ?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth you could use a statically-allocated buffer of sufficient size.

Comment: Your function shall return a pointer to char. What do you want it to point to? The concatenated string of course. But where do you think that sequence of chars should be located? Malloc is the answer to that.

Comment: i would prefer without because i am writing a code for someone else and i don't want to do a malloc here because he don't have to use free // i don't know if that mada any sense

Comment: Well you can spare him to use free, or you can spare him to do the definition of a buffer (see e.g. answer below). Pick one. Requiring him to do free() spares all the annoying thinking about sizes; at least if it is done right inside the function.

Comment: If you don't want him to have to call `free`, how do you want the lifetime of the buffer to be managed? Do you want the caller to manage it however they want?

Comment: ok thank you i understand :)

Comment: @Dai ...and so make the function thread-unsafe :(

Comment: BTW: the `- 1` in `char *str = malloc ( size);
    snprintf ( str, size - 1, "%d-%02d", day, hour);` was not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without `malloc` only if the caller passes you the buffer for the string:

```
static void intToTimeDate(int day, int hour, char *buf, size_t sz){
    snprintf ( buf, sz, "%d-%02d", day, hour);
}
```

Now the caller can pass a buffer, and get the string back:

```
char buf[32];
intToTimeDate(day, hour, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

Comment: i am saving this in a random struct actually :/ and i don't know which one so i don't know how i would recognize the struct in my code when i want to use free , but i will figure it out eventually i guess

Comment: @mamama No freeing is necessary, but if you put a `buf` pointer to a `struct`, you cannot return it from the function where `buf` is declared to avoid undefined behavior.